# Translations of layout handle label

Tags: layout, localisation

During the creation of a layout handle you specify a node `<label>` which is some text to describe the layout handle. For example the layout handle `catalog_category_default` has the following defined.

```
<label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
```

As part of the layout handle you can specify to translate these labels `<catalog_category_default translate="label">`. Which makes sense if these labels are shown some place but I am not sure if or where they are shown to a user and so would require translation.

Comment: I did some research and couldn't find anything. Maybe it was just a good habit of the developer to have always the label tag written for an eventual latter use.

Comment: @SamuelComan could be. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about Widget Instance section? You have a Layout Update to select there for the instance you're about to create and the drop-down menu presents a list of them with labels.

I assume they're translated accordingly in case you change the locale of the Admin panel.

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose of the `<label>` node.